# Adding unique items to dictionary from data frame

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to make a dictionary of 30 NBA teams from a length 1200 data frame column of team names.  I only want each team to appear once in the dictionary and be paired to an integer from 0-29.  I've been having a difficult time iterating, what I have so far only adds the first value from the data frame to the dictionary.

```
df1 = df[['team_1']]

teams = dict()

index = 0

for key in df1:

    if key in teams:

        continue
    else:

        teams[key] = index
        index = index + 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `df` is a Pandas DataFrame, you could use a [`dict comprehension`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
teams = {team:i for i, team in enumerate(df['team_1'].unique())}
```